# How to use aggregations while creating the variables in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Can anybody please tell me how to use aggregate functions in the variables ? When I use any aggregate function like sum,max etc, it is showing me

> you should not use aggregate functions at variables.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: *When i use any aggregate function...* Show us what you did.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  An example would be nice...

Comment: Why do you want to use aggregate function on a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was trying use aggregate function(sum,Max etc) while creating variables with if condition
but i wrote only if condition and used the aggregate function at report level it worked